Email was delayed in WP project
I have a WP project that have several cron jobs such as sending email to admin's email address everyday.
This email is a kinda reports of the website so it's a bit important for me.
I am currently using Daily Printouts plugin for sending email and also set the WP project's timezone correctly.
e.g timezone: Europe/Berlin - UTC+2
sending email time: 07:00 - Daily
image1
image2
But unfortunately this email arrived to admin for 2 hours later. So it arrived to me 09:00 at UTC+2.
Of course, we can set the sending email time to 05:00, but I really want to know why this delay is happening.
What can I do in order to change that to the expected timing?
